# Checking if text file is empty Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to check if a text file is empty in Python WITHOUT using os ?

What I have tried so far

```
x = open("friends.txt")
friendsfile = x.readlines()

if friendsfile == None
```

But I don't think it's the correct way.

Comment: why can't you use the os?

Comment: The solution is in the link given by @Andy. Duplicate confirmed.

Comment: No i dont think there is a solution at that link, please note he does not wanna use os.

Comment: Its memory intensive to open the file to check if it's empty, if all you want is to check if the file is empty. if the file is already open, then you can use the answer from the link provided by Andy.

Comment: Note that your solution could be fixed to become correct if you changed `if friendsfile == None` to `if friendsfile == []` (`[]` is the empty list, and `readlines` returns a list) or just `if not friendsfile` (since `[]` is treated as false). However the given answer is definitely more efficient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure why you wouldn't use `os`, but I suppose if you really wanted you could open the file and get the first character.

```
with open('friends.txt') as friendsfile:
    first = friendsfile.read(1)
    if not first:
        print('friendsfile is empty')
    else:
        #do something
```

Comment: with open('friends.txt') as friendsfile:
     if friendsfile == []:
        print('friendsfile is empty')
    else:
        #do something ....... gives you the same with one line less

Comment: wrong answer. if the first line is just a new line and nothing else on the file. it counts as one which is true

Comment: @AbdullahSaid as it should?